# Undefined Variable - Do Switch Statements have scope in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, scope, switch-statement

Hello to all this is my first time posting, thought it would be good since im utterly stuck. It was my understanding that switch and If/else statements in PHP do not have variable scope.

My issue is I have a CSV file ( a sample one) with about 5 rows of values and I need to get it put into a mySQL DB table( the column headers are represented in my "cases" for my switch statement) BUt anyways I'm parsing the CSV file and checking to make sure that the data is in the column it should be and storing it in a variable. I am then storing all of the variables in an array that is getting serialized and then getting passed into a my SQL query.

I continue to get the error 
 SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: company in C:\wamp\www\lcimport\serialize.php on line 98

But I know those variables are there cause I can echo them and they will be called. But unless those errors go away my query will not run thus not populating my db table.

what am I doing wrong?

```
   <?php
//define some constants
$db = 'lc';
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
mysql_select_db($db);
 mysql_error();
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

//we only have this here to be a row counter
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("C:\\wamp\\www\\lcimport\\4records.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        //var_dump($data);
       // echo $data[0];
        echo '';
        if ($row === 1) {
        $header = $data;
       }     

        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            if ($row === 2) continue;
             switch ($header[$c] ){
              case "Contact":
                      $contact = explode (" ", $data[$c]);
                      $firstName =  $contact[0];
                      $lastName =  $contact[1];
              break;

              case "Company":
                    $company = $data[$c];


              case "Address1":
              //store
                    $address1 = $data[$c];

              break;

              case "Address2":
                    $address2 = $data[$c];

              break;

              case "Address3":
                    $address3 = $data[$c];

              break;

              case "City":
                    $city = $data[$c];

              break;

              case "State":
                    $state = $data[$c];

              break;

              case "Zip":
                    $zip = $data[$c];

              break;

              case "Phone1":
                    $phone1 = $data[$c];
              break;

              case "Phone2":
                     $phone2 = $data[$c];
              break; 

              case "Phone 3":
                    $phone3 = $data[$c];
              break;

              case "Fax":
                    $fax = $data[$c];
              break;          

              case "Accountno":
                    $accountNo = $data[$c];
              break;

              default:
                $junk = $data[$c];
              break;


             }




        }       
        echo $company;  
            $meta = serialize(Array(
                    "firstname" => $firstName,
                    "lastname" => $lastName,
                    "lawfirmname" => $company,
                    'address' => $address1,
                    'city' => $city,
                    'state' => $state,
                    'zip' => $zip,
                    'fulladdress' => '',
                    'officenumber' => $phone1,
                    'faxnumber' => $fax,
                    'mobilenumber' => $phone2,
                    'email' =>'nothing',
                    'website' => 'somthing.com',
                    'privacy' => 0,
                    'status' =>1
                    )); 




        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mg_profiles` (meta) VALUES ($meta)");
        mysql_error();

    }
    fclose($handle);
    }


?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has something to do with it: `if ($row === 2) continue;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If every else variables are existing and works correctly**, then the missing `break;` should be the problem on the case of Company.

It is not a good idea to communicate with a relational database within a loop, it is more memory and process efficient to store the results to an array and after all data has ben got, just insert with a simple request, because

```
INSERT INTO `mg_profiles` (meta) VALUES (...), (...), (...)
```

works perfectly.

PHP has a [command](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to handle processes like this:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
    if ($row == 1 || $row == 2) {
        $row++;
        continue;
    }
    list ($contact, $company, $address1 /*, ...*/) = $data;
}
```

Comment: The multiple insert works until you hit the maximum query length, at which point you need to split the query into chunks.

Comment: This helped me incredibly! Completely forgot about the list() function, it solved my problem thank you. If I could upvote I would

Answer (score 0):

Just define it before the conditional statement (before the if())

```
$company = '';
```

Since $company comes up only inside a conditional statement, when condition fails, it wud be undefined, hence the error