# PHP set variable in function within switch within foreach

Tags: php, switch-statement, scope

I need to declare a bunch of variables within a function based on data which is looped through using a `foreach` with a `switch` statement with another `foreach`. I think I'm misunderstanding the scope of the variables I'm using, any help would be great.

```
class Users {

    public function createUserData(){
        $user = $this->getUserData(); //not shown function
        $this->createFullDataSet($user);
    }

    private function createFullDataSet($user){
        foreach( $user['meta'][0] as $key => $value) {
        //variables required later
        $entity_def_id = 0;
        $entity_id = 0;
        $data_def_id = 0;
        $user_id = 0;
        //thats plenty, you get the idea

        switch( $key ){
           case "id":
               //set $user_id to use later
               $user_id = $value; // <<-- DOESN'T WORK, only works within the case
               break;
           case "email":
           case "username":
           case //lots of other cases...
               break;
           case "location":
           case "hometown":
           case "something":
               //for the last three, the data structure is the same, good test case
               //foreach starts when certain conditions met, irrelevant for question
               foreach( $value as $data_key => $data_value ){
                   $data_type = 'string';
                   if( is_numeric( $data_value )
                       $data_type = 'integer';

                   $data_def_id = $this->createDataDef( some $vars ); //returns an ID using $pdo->lastInsertId(); ( works as has echo'd correctly, at least within this case )

                   $this->createSomethingElse //with variables within this foreach, works
               }
               break;
            } //end of switch
            $this->createRelation( $data_def_id ); // <<-- DOESN'T WORK!! Empty variable
        }
    }

    private function createRelation( $data_def_id ){
        // something awesome happens!
    }
}
```

As can be seen from the above code, I want to use a variable outside of the switch statement, though it needs to be declared in `foreach`->`switch`->`foreach` due to existing data structure (this data structure is a pain and is why this needs to be done, before anyone asks: no can't "just be changed to make it easier").

Now I've been reading up on the variable scopes of foreach and switch statements ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306263/php-switch-statement-variable-scope), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392132/undefined-variable-do-switch-statements-have-scope-in-php), [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and [here](http://www.phptutorial.be/variable-scope.html) and tried to find more), however none the wiser as to why the `$data_def_id`, at the start of the function set to `0`, doesn't get reset to whatever value comes along in the inner `foreach`. I'm trying to avoid using `global` variables as some of this functionality will be used in a product.

I need to be able to use the variables within the `private function`, throughout the whole private function (including the `foreach`, `switch`, etc). What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the answer.

```
class Users {

    public function createUserData(){
        $user = $this->getUserData(); //not shown function
        $this->createFullDataSet($user);
    }

    private function createFullDataSet($user){//variables required later
        static $entity_def_id = 0; //static within function instead of non-static within foreach
        static $entity_id = 0;
        static $data_def_id = 0;
        static $user_id = 0;
        //thats plenty, you get the idea
        foreach( $user['meta'][0] as $key => $value) {
            //remainder of that method with switch( foreach () )
        }
    }

    private function createRelation( $data_def_id ){
        // something awesome happens!
    }
}
```

By declaring the variables as `static` within the function, the whole of the function, including methods within can use the variables. Took me me long enough :s.

Comment: you are right. It makes more sense to declare function specific variables inside of the function rather than the whole class. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

How about you define them as `class properties`?

```
class User {

    private $data_def_id;

    private function createFullDataSet($user){
        //....
        $this->data_def_id = $this->createDataDef( some $vars );

    }
}
```

Comment: Could work, but seems rather messy to me. That would have me create a whole lot of variables. The data is incredibly dynamic, changing on the fly, it would become a pain to ensure each time that it has been reset to `0` or `null` before starting a function requiring those variables. (`0` or `null` to be able to check them with `empty()` or `isset()`)

Comment: you can do that after every round of your `for` loop. Eventhough it might be messy it should work :P

Comment: True, would work. But if/when a fellow coder comes along all hell would break lose ;) Will keep it in mind though, more of a last resort type solution, with a giant `//TO DO: make something elegant out of this` ;)

Comment: Found it! Neater than class variables ;) Thanks for your help nonetheless!